# what is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, summation, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I posted a question earlier about the taylor of $(1-x)\ln(1-x)$ but i made a miscalculation and decided to delete it, sorry about that.

anyways, i solved the miscalculation and i found that $(1-x)\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Now I just need to combine these two sums into a single sum, and get something of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ and I can't seem to do it without something straggling outside of the sum.

how do i proceed from here?

Edit: we know $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$, so $\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^nx^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-x^n}{n}$

and so $(1-x)\ln(1-x)=(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-x^n}{n}=(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Comment: Write the first sum as $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n-1}$ then check that $\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but that means we will have index mismatch, since the first sum starts at $n=2$ and the second one at $n=1$. So we will have $-x$ out of the summation

Comment: it does not look as a big issue.

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}-x$

Comment: I'm not sure $-x+\sum a_nx^n$ counts as taylor series.

Comment: A Taylor series is determined by the values of some  derivatives in zero, regardless if they have a nice expression or not.

Answer (score 0):

What only became clear from the comments, it that you want to present it as a Taylor series.  This is almost trivial:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n} \tag  1\\
&= -x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)x^n \tag 2\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\
\end{align}$$
with
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
0, & \text { if } n=0 \\
-1, & \text { if } n=1 \\
\dfrac{1}{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac1{n(n-1)}, &\text{ if } n\geqslant 2\\
\end{cases}$$

So that $(2)$ is clearly a Tylor series (around 0 with radius of convergence of 1).

The sum $(2)$ converges because the two sums of $(1)$ do converge.